# How to remove wsu:id and namespace declaration by xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

I would like to remove the attribute Id and the namespace in the tag soap:Body by using XSLT.

My sample soap response to transform is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body wsu:Id="Body-a3aedbad-1ef4-44a9-9982-bfa5cf9fe25f" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis- 
    open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <soap:Fault>         
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My already implemented xslt is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    exclude-result-prefixes="wsu">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
        indent="yes" />
        
    <!-- remove attribute Id with prefix wsu -->
    <xsl:template match="@wsu:Id" />

    <!-- removed unused namespace declarations in soap:Body, especially xlmns:wsu -->
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Body']">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    

    <!-- copy all other elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output: is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">      
            
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The ouput should be

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>         
            
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The attribute and the namespace is removed. The problem is that the namespace declaration is inherited to the child objects. Can anyone tell me a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2):

The second template, instead of matching `<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='Body']">`, needs to match `<xsl:template match="soap:Body | soap:Body//*">`. In addition, the namespaces in the XSLT, for reason I don't understand, differ from the ones in the XML, so you need to adapt the namespace declarations in the XSLT to say

```
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
```

(this assumes the line break in the wsu namespace in the posted sample is a formatting error).

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your response. If I change the xslt to your suggested solution, no wsu namespace declaration is removed.

Comment: @Joezi, I didn't notice that your namespace used in the XML and XSLT differ, although the namespace prefixes used, like `soap`, suggest you want to match the elements from the input. So you need to ensure the namespaces match, i.e. change the namespace declarations in the XSLT, see the edited answer.

Comment: Now, it works. Many thanks. It was a mismatch between the namespace in xslt and the xml. Thanks a much!